# RDBMS ANSI-SQL Compatible

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Is there some way to check if the SQL engine of a particular RDBMS is ANSI-SQL compatible?

Answer (score 1):

SQL has different implementations and each of which may have extra features over the standard SQL or maybe not support some standard features.

You can see these links:

- https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/business/comparing-database-management-systems-mysql-postgresql-mssql-server-mongodb-elasticsearch-and-others/

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization

- https://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/